# Como o flask entende as condições passadas para filter(), se elas são avaliadas antes da função ser chamada

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Olá, gente!

Minha dúvida é pontual, mas não consegui encontrar em outro lugar. Então vamos a ela:

quando queremos, por exemplo, encontrar um usuário na nossa base de dados que tenha um email dado, fazemos `User.query.filter(User.email == email)`. A minha dúvida é exatamente aqui: se eu construir uma função e tentar passar um argumento dessa forma (Classe.AtributoDaClasse == Variavel), a condição é avaliada e o argumento que a função de fato acessa é um boleano, com verdadeiro ou falso, dependendo dos valores de Class.`AtributoDaClasse` e `Variavel`. Mas a função filter() não pode receber um boleano, com verdadeiro ou falso. A correta filtragem depende de qual atributo está sendo verificado, e do valor que está sendo procurado.

Então a grande dúvida fica ai: como a função tem acesso ao atributo da classe que está sendo verificado se isso não chega lá? Existe algo de especial que funções do flask tem que as funções que eu crio "na mão" não tem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você está descrevendo aqui é o chamado "unpacking" ou "desempacotamento de argumentos". Quando você chama uma função e passa uma série de argumentos separados por vírgula, esses argumentos são "empacotados" em uma tupla e passados para a função. Quando você usa o operador de atribuição "==" para comparar um atributo de classe com um valor, você está criando uma expressão booleana que é avaliada como verdadeira ou falsa.

Mas quando você usa o operador de atribuição "==" dentro de uma chamada de função, o Python não avalia a expressão imediatamente. Em vez disso, ele cria um objeto chamado "expressão filtro" que representa a expressão booleana. Quando a função é chamada, o Python passa esse objeto como um argumento para a função, em vez do valor booleano avaliado da expressão.

A função filter() pode usar essa expressão filtro para avaliar cada elemento da sequência e decidir se ele deve ser incluído no resultado final ou não. No caso de uma consulta do SQLAlchemy, a função filter() é usada para criar uma cláusula WHERE na consulta SQL gerada pelo SQLAlchemy. Quando a consulta é executada no banco de dados, a expressão filtro é avaliada para cada linha da tabela e a linha é incluída no resultado final se a expressão for avaliada como verdadeira.

Espero que isso ajude a esclarecer a situação. Se você tiver mais alguma dúvida, por favor, estou por aqui.

Comment: É necessário algo para que as funções entendam esse objeto "expressão filtro"? Porque em criei funções na mão, e quando tento interagir com os argumentos eles sempre estão avaliados ja, eu não tenho de fato acesso aos elementos desse filtro. Você sabe como implementar algo que acesse a expressão filtro e extraia dados deles? Tem um exemplo de código ou referência na documentação pra isso? Nao consegui encontrar

Comment: Eu acho que você está falando sobre o uso de filtros em expressões do AngularJS. Os filtros são usados ​​para transformar os dados de uma expressão antes de exibi-los para o usuário.

Para acessar os elementos de um filtro em uma expressão, você pode usar a função $filter do AngularJS. Essa função aceita o nome do filtro como primeiro argumento e os argumentos do filtro como os demais argumentos. Por exemplo:

    $filter('nomeDoFiltro')(argumentosDoFiltro);

Comment: Por exemplo, suponha que você tenha um filtro chamado reverse que inverte a ordem dos elementos de uma string ou array. Você pode acessar esse filtro da seguinte maneira:

<code> $filter('reverse')('abc');  // retorna 'cba'
$filter('reverse')([1, 2, 3]);  // retorna [3, 2, 1]</code>